# Assign a constant and use it during the SQL queries

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am using the pandas to read the data from SQL tables.

Since I have a lot of join and etc computation, I have to use the limit in my code.

So, in multiple lines of my code I have for example, `limit 100`.
How can I assign a constant to put after limit then all of the lines updated and don't need to go over all the lines to update?

For example I assign a constant as `a= 100` and then I used the `limit a` in my code. Here is a simple example which I have with two limits.

```
feature1 = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100""", db1)

feature2 = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100""", db2)
```

I want something like this:

```
a = 100
feature1 = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT a""", db1)
feature2 = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT a""", db2)
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using an f-string:

```
>>> a = 100
>>> print(f"""SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT {a}""")
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100
```

As long as your code controls the value of `a`, this is safe. It doesn't conflict with general advice against SQL injection. If the value of `a` comes from an untrusted source, then you should use a query parameter.